# No boot partition at all, but the server still boots up

Tags: linux, boot-partition

```
[dj-web01]~> blkid
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="d7469ff8-6ce7-470e-a4c3-295ea295ca82" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="076fccb9-ff55-4c41-bf6d-c6a71b605006" TYPE="swap"


--

[dj-web01]~> cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d7469ff8-6ce7-470e-a4c3-295ea295ca82 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=076fccb9-ff55-4c41-bf6d-c6a71b605006 none            swap    sw              0       0
[dj-web01]~> 

--

[dj-web01]~> lshw -class disk
  *-disk                  
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       size: 50GiB (53GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=00022491
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       capabilities: audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: signature=56d7f18d status=ready
[dj-web01]~> 
---
[dj-web01]~> fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders, total 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00022491

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   100663295    50330624   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       100665342   104855551     2095105    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       100665344   104855551     2095104   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

and also it hangs here

```
Need to get 74.2 MB/301 MB of archives.
After this operation, 286 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main grub-pc-bin amd64 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7 [882 kB]
1% [1 grub-pc-bin 882 kB/882 kB 100%]
```

Update

```
[dj-web01]~> mount 
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
--
[dj-web01]~> df   
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1013988       8   1013980   1% /dev
tmpfs             204968     536    204432   1% /run
/dev/sda1       49409840 8112424  38764504  18% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1024840       0   1024840   0% /run/shm
none              102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
```

Comment: What "boot partition" are you referring to? A separate partition for `/boot` is never a compulsory thing.

Comment: Is the "hangs here" your actual question/problem?

Answer (score 0):

What is your question?
GRUB can boot from MBR area ,and has modules to access files in ext4 partitions.
Only in GPT there is a need for a BIOS boot partition or EFI partition

As for the hang,can you provide

- **mount** info ?
- **df** free space ?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: how long did you try to wait for the `apt-get install` command completion ? have you tried looking at `iostat` IO utilization? is this a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your issue.

Your partition with the boot flag is the following :

```
>    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> /dev/sda1   *        2048   100663295    50330624   83  Linux
```

It refers at your "/" ext4 partition.

Comment: it hangs about 4-5 minutes on each line 
  uno-libs3 ure
124 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 74.2 MB/300 MB of archives.
After this operation, 286 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main grub-pc-bin amd64 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7 [882 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main grub-pc-bin amd64 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7 [882 kB]
1% [3 grub-pc-bin 882 kB/882 kB 100%]